# How to display an other custom post type in a different custom post type's archive?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, query-posts, custom-post-type-archives

**Background:**

I need to display all posts of a custom post type called "recipes", that have a specific taxonomy "fish", right under the permalink "www.mysite.com/recipes/fish".

**What I have done:**

I created two custom post types:

1) One custom post type called "recipes" with the archive slug "www.mysite.com/recipes" to display all posts of that post type. That works fine.

2) Another custom post type called "fish" and rewrote the permalink to "www.mysite.com/recipes/fish". But actually there is no use for this post type. I have only created it to get this custom archive link "www.mysite.com/recipes/fish".

Now I changed the WP_Query right before the post loop if it is is_post_type_archive ('fish') to

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
         'post_type' => 'recipes',
         'tax_query' => array(
                         array(
                          'taxonomy' => 'category',
                          'field'    => 'slug',
                          'terms'    => 'fish'
                         )
                        ),
         'posts_per_page' => '10',
         'order'          => 'DESC',
         'paged'          => $paged
        );     
$newloop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The first page of that archive "www.mysite.com/recipes/fish" works fine, too. I can see a list of the ten newest recipes that have the custom taxonomy "fish".

**But there is one huge problem:**

I created more than 10 recipes and listed them under "fish". But when I visit "www.mysite.com/recipes/fish/page/2" it tells me "Oops! That page can’t be found." Maybe because the actual post type "fish" has not more than one normal archive pages.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

It is really important that I have the link structure "www.mysite.com/recipes/fish" for "recipes" with the taxonomy "fish" but when visiting a single recipe it should only be a permalink like "www.mysite.com/recipes/my-tasty-fish-recipe".

That is why I tried to do it this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But you didn't create a taxonomy for your recipes.  You created two completely unrelated post types.  Look up WP register_taxonomy().